# paste and awk error inside perl script

Tags: perl, awk

I used

```
paste Output1.txt Output2.txt | awk '{print $1, $2, $5, $15}'
```

inside perl script by using system(awk_commamd).
I am getting error like

```
awk: {print , , , }
awk:        ^ syntax error
```

Need help to sort this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Perl is interpolating variables into your string, use single quotes instead:

```
system('paste Output1.txt Output2.txt | awk \'{print $1, $2, $5, $15}\'');
```

or:

```
system(q(paste Output1.txt Output2.txt | awk '{print $1, $2, $5, $15}'));
```

in any case, it is better to do this all in Perl without using `system` for increased performance, readability, and portability.

Comment: Thank you, now am able to run my script with out error

Comment: Given perl seems to have a million language constructs to do the most obscure things, any idea why we so often see questions about how to call other UNIX tools (awk, grep, etc.) from perl?

Comment: @EdMorton, Since shell scripting is, often, stringing together multiple tools, I can see why people with some shell scripting experience start with this kind of code. But they will learn :)

Comment: Ah, so people are trying to use perl as a shell rather than a self-contained tool. I guess I can see that... Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6):

Duplicating the work of `paste` and `awk` using pure perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @fhs = map {open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh} qw(Output1.txt Output2.txt);

while (grep {!eof $_} @fhs) {
    my @lines = map {(scalar <$_>) // ''} @fhs;
    chomp @lines;
    my @fields = split ' ', join "\t", @lines;

    print join("\t", grep defined, @fields[0,1,4,14]), "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1, eof should use explicit file handle => `!eof($_)` as `An eof without an argument uses the last file read`.

Comment: `join "\t", @lines` could also be `"@lines"`, and perhaps `scalar` can be dropped as it's already in scalar context.

Comment: @mpapec Updated code for `eof` (feel free to update yourself next time I make a mistake.  It'll happen ;).  As for the use of `scalar`, it is superfluous because `// ''` forces a scalar context.  However, without that it will slurp entire file so I feel it's best to leave it in to communicate intent.